# ODataQueryOptions ApplyTo and return a single result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, .net-5

I have an endpoint that performs some specialized business logic. The result of which is a DTO that includes some information about the action performed, as well as the updated entity. I'd like to give my API users control over how much data is returned by allowing them to supply some OData query options.

Example:

```
POST /api/v1/Listings/34734/SpecialAction?$select=id,name&$expand=comments($top=2)
{
   //some data used to perform action
}

RESPONSE
{
   /*fields always included:*/
   actionResults: {
      someField: "foo"
      anotherField: "bar"
   },

   /*queryable entity*/
   listing: {
       id: 34734,
       name: "Super Cool Listing",
       comments: [
          {id: 34834, text: "a comment" },
          {id: 34834, text: "another comment" }
       ]
   }
}
```

The problem however, is that `ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo` only returns a type of `IQueryable`, whereas `SingleResult.Create` requires an `IQueryable<T>`. How can I manually apply the query opts and return a single result?

```
[HttpPost("{key}/SpecialAction")]
public IActionResult SpecialAction(Guid key, ODataQueryOptions<Listing> opts)
{
    //Perform the action
    var actionResults = _specialActionService.performTheAction(key);

    //Grab only the results requested by the API user (e.g. specific fields, expanded entities, etc)
    IQueryable queryable = opts.ApplyTo(_db.Listing.Where(x => x.id == key))
    
    //Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyService.Models.Listing>'
    var singleReult = SingleResult.Create<Listing>(queryable);

    return Ok(new {
        listing = singleResult,
        actionResults = actionResults
    });
}
```

I am using .NET 5 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.3